# Hibernate fails create sessionfactory using HikariCP pool

Tags: hibernate, sessionfactory, hikaricp

I try to use HikariCP pool connection, but I can't make app starts because I get all time, a null object from create sesion.

This is my configuration:

**System**

- Hibernate 4.3.6.Final
- MariaDB v10.0 (x64)

**HibernateUtil class**

```
public class HibernateUtil {
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        return sessionFactory;
    }
    catch (HibernateException ex) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if (sessionFactory == null) {
        sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
    }
    return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Datos de conexión a la BD -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/******?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">****</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">****</property>
        <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</property>
        <!-- Configuración de sesión -->
        <property name="connection.release_mode">after_transaction</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <!-- Configuración de la salida SQL y estadísticas -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
        <!-- Pool de conexiones -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLDataSource</property>
        <!-- Enable Hibernate's current session context -->
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**LOG**

> Preparing to build session factory with filters : 
>   {} HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLDataSource
>   Exception in Application start method

Comment: What version of HikariCP are you using and what Java version? If you enable debug logging, is additional information logged?

Comment: I enable debug level (sorry I have disabled before) and I get this error `nov 07, 2014 12:09:11 PM com.util.HibernateUtil buildSessionFactory
GRAVE: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]`

Comment: I use HikariCP 2.1.0 and Java 1.8.0_40-ea (b11). App is a JavaFX project. Also, I use MySQL Connector 5.1.33

Comment: You say you are using HikariCP, but the hibernate.connection.provider.class is point at the MySQLDataSource rather than the HikariCP hibernate connection provider.  You need to consult the hibernate connection provider documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As brettw say, I only need to change the provider class to

```
<prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider</prop>
```